# navigating to component twice giving error for setstate

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a small application in react-native with two components.
on Navigating to a component twice this gives me error for setState function.
Anybody have idea about this .
I am using native base as an starter kit for my project.
the only change I did is I have seperated the UI render part in different js file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Comment: I am just asking about the public github starter kit on react-native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this has something to do with your render function.
the setstate function gives error when there is no such state variable available.
may be on navigating again to that same screen it is giving you a new state for that page instead of the previous state.
Please check your render function.

Comment: thanks for the answer I will check my function and will let you know.

Comment: my render function is actually on another file do you think it might be the issue?

Comment: render() {
    return loginRenderer.renderLogin();
  }
I am importing render js file on the page and binding the context of the main screen to render screen.

Comment: aah bingo, that might be the issue why don't you pass context in the render function like this " 
return loginRenderer.renderLogin(this); "
and use that as a ref in you renderer js function.
the reason might be because you are binding a different context and the setState is on different context of the compoenent.

Comment: great that worked thank you very much I was stuck in this issue for a while.